# Python format localized date time without the seconds?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, format

In Python, how can I format the current time in localized (regional appropriate) date and time format *without* the seconds?

For example, the output below should hot have the `:41` in the output, but it should preserve all other regional features such as: the the ordering of the day and month, the month abbreviation, the 12hr or 24hr format, the AM or PM indicator, etc.

(Note that I explicitly set different locales below for testing purposes only, but I will be relying on the system set local).

```
import time
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
'en_US.UTF-8'
time.strftime('%x %X')
'12/11/2020 07:35:41 PM'
time.strftime('%c')
'Fri 11 Dec 2020 07:35:41 PM EST'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF-8')
'en_GB.UTF-8'
time.strftime('%x %X')
'11/12/20 19:35:41'
time.strftime('%c')
'Fri 11 Dec 2020 19:35:41 EST'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_CA.UTF-8')
'en_CA.UTF-8'
time.strftime('%x %X')
'2020-12-11 07:35:41 PM'
time.strftime('%c')
'Fri 11 Dec 2020 07:35:41 PM'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_AU.UTF-8')
'en_AU.UTF-8'
time.strftime('%x %X')
'11/12/20 19:35:41'
time.strftime('%c')
'Fri 11 Dec 2020 19:35:41'
```

Comment: Why not use other strptime directives? E.g. one that has `%H:%M` and no `%S`?

Comment: I want to start with a current time object and convert it to a human readable string adhering to regional conventions (containing day, month, year, hour, minute, perhaps TZ). strptime expects a string as input, but I have a time object. Some cultures show the day before the month; others show 24 hr vs 12 hr format. I would need to check each locale, decide what time format they use, and then create a custom format string containing different directives (such as "%I"  or "%H" for the hour and appending a "%p" for AM/PM). There should be an easier way, rather than coding all this complex logic?

Comment: Ok got your point ;-) Since there is %c, %x and %X, this has been coded already, no need to repeat of course. But configuring this (no seconds) seems to contradict the idea of the pre-defined format, right? Anyway, can't think of a simple way right now, other than post-processing the string.